# How do I get innerHtml using Nokogiri gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parsing, nokogiri

e.g. i have html:

```
<div class="item">
    <p>
        bla bla<br/>
        bla bla
    </p>
</div>
```

i need to get inner html of div.item:

```
 <p>
    bla bla<br/>
    bla bla
 </p>
```

i know that i can use:

```
doc.css("div.item:first").text
```

text method return clean text without any html tags

but what should i do for getting inner html of div.item?

tried:

```
doc.css("div.item:first").html
```

but doesn't work, documentation did not help as well

any ideas?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If you just need the string:

```
doc.css("div.item:first").inner_html
```