# What is proper way to validate element's text length in Capybara?

Tags: ruby, cucumber, capybara

I am using Capybara with cucumber and ruby

```
env.rb
Capybara.current_driver = :selenium
```

I have a web site in many languages and I want to verify following element that should have text with minimum length of 100 characters, otherwise, show a message

```
<p id="user_text">sometext</p>
```

The text in "user_text" could be in any language, so

```
(("#user_text").text.length > 99) == true

Element.should have_content?("text") won't work because I don't know the text in "user_text"
```

Above method is not work and always passes.

How I would verify the length of text and on failure print a message ?

Any answer will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Just a clarification:*

When you're calling `Element.should` you are really using [RSpec predicate matchers](http://rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-expectations/file/README.md#Predicate_matchers), so:

`Element.should have_content?("text")`

really just calls the:

`Element.has_content?("text")`

so it does the same thing, but the second examples uses [Capybara node matcher](http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Matchers).

*Going back to your question*

You can also use other [RSpec matchers](http://rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-expectations/file/README.md#Built-in_matchers) in your tests. And since Capybara uses Nokogiri, your Element is really a [Nokogiri::XML::Node](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/CSS/Node.html) here. So you can use the `text` method to get to the content and verify it, like this:

`Element.text.should match(/^.{99,}$/)`

This should do what you need. You can use `text` or `inner_html` methods [depending on what you want to check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7697662/how-do-i-get-innerhtml-using-nokogiri-gem).