# How to remove specific tags but leave allowed tags

Tags: html, ruby, parsing, nokogiri

In some HTML, I'd like to remove some specific tags but leave the tag's contents/HTML in place. For example, in the line below, I 
want to remove the `<strong>` and `<div>` blacklisted tags but leave the contents of the tags in place, and leave the `<p>`, `<img>` and other tags from my whitelist tags alone:

Original:

```
<div>
    some text
    <strong>text</strong>
    <p>other text</p>
    <img src="http://example.com" />
</div>
```

Result:

```
some text
text
<p>other text</p>
<img src="http://example.com" />
```

I want strip specific tags and some tags must not be stripped. It must work like [`strip_tags`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) in PHP. So `inner_html` can't help me with it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get innerHtml using Nokogiri gem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7697662/how-do-i-get-innerhtml-using-nokogiri-gem)

Comment: @lcguida - no, because I want remove specified tags, and you suggest get inner_html. It is different things. Please read description carefully

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19861338/remove-a-tag-but-keep-the-text

Comment: @hakcho please read answer Alexey Shein, it is not duplicate. Please read description carefully

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`Rails::Html::WhiteListSanitizer`](https://github.com/rails/rails-html-sanitizer):

```
white_list_sanitizer = Rails::Html::WhiteListSanitizer.new
original = <<EOD
<div>
     some text
     <strong>text</strong>
     <p>other text</p>
     <img src="http://example.com" />
</div>
EOD

puts white_list_sanitizer.sanitize(original, tags: %w(p img))
```

Output:

```
some text
text
<p>other text</p>
<img src="http://example.com">
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. I will try your code, if it help me - I will mark your question as correct. Use only Nokogiri will be better (because I am using it to prepare html), but this way is also possible

Comment: Do you prefer a non-Rails solution? This is actually a lightweight wrapper around https://github.com/flavorjones/loofah gem (which uses nokogiri in its turn). If you need it, I can post some code using this gem only, let me know.

Comment: Recent Rails versions also provide [`sanitize`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper.html#method-i-sanitize) as a helper directly. No need to instantiate any classes.

Answer (score 6):

I'd do something like:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(<<EOT)
<div>
    some text
    <strong>text</strong>
    <p>other text</p>
    <img src="http://example.com" />
</div>
EOT

BLACKLIST = %w[strong div]

doc.search(BLACKLIST.join(',')).each do |node|
  node.replace(node.children)
end

puts doc.to_html
# >> <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
# >> <html><body>
# >>     some text
# >>     text
# >>     <p>other text</p>
# >>     <img src="http://example.com">
# >> 
# >> </body></html>
```

Basically it looks for the nodes in `BLACKLIST` and finds them anywhere in the document, replacing them with the `children` of the node, effectively promoting the child node(s) to their parent.

Answer (score 0):

In you want to use only Nokogiri, you could loop over the nodes to remove recursively all the unwanted tags:

```
def clean_node(node, whitelist)
  node.children.each do |n|
    clean_node(n, whitelist)
    unless whitelist.include?(n.name)
      n.before(n.children)
      n.remove
    end
  end
  node
end

def strip_tags(html, whitelist)
  whitelist += %w(text)
  node = Nokogiri::HTML(html).children.last
  clean_node(node, whitelist).inner_html
end
```

The `strip_tags` function will remove all the tags who are not in the whitelist. For your example, you would do:

```
original = <<HTML
<div>
     some text
     <strong>text</strong>
     <p>other text</p>
     <img src="http://example.com" />
</div>
HTML

puts strip_tags(original, %w(p img))
```

The output is:

```
 some text
 text
 <p>other text</p>
 <img src="http://example.com">
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, but why I must use `Nokogiri::XML`? now I am using `Nokogiri::HTML`...

Comment: You're right. I was writing a general solution for any XML. I replace `Nokogiri::XML` by `Nokogiri::HTML` in my answer to be specific to html.

Answer (score -1):

You could use the xmp tag to display HTML tags.

```
<div>
    some text
    <strong>text</strong>
    <xmp><p>other text</p>
    <img src="http://example.com" />
    </xmp>
</div>
```

The HTML Element "xmp" renders text between the start and end tags without interpreting the HTML.